# Please give an example code(Android) for populating 3 spinners from a JSON file like (converter, zone, code)

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have 3 spinners and I want to parse JSON data into them. For example the JSON file structure has Converterno, zoneno and codeid . So i want to populate all the converter no. in one spinner and zoneno. in another spinner and similarly the 3rd spinner. Iam trying this in android and trying to parse data from json. Please help.
My xml file is fine, just need help in java class to get the values to dropdown

Here is the latest code (Selectcode.java) i did with the help of @Lucefer

```
package com.example.com;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class selectcode extends AppCompatActivity {
      String URL = "*url_to_json_php*";
      List<String> converter = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> zone = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> codeid = new ArrayList<>();
      JSONObject jsonObject;
      JSONArray jsonArray;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selectcode);
        try{
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(URL);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                converter.add(jsonObject.optString("converternumber"));
                zone.add(jsonObject.optString("zonenumber"));
                codeid.add(jsonObject.optString("codeid"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Spinner spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectconverter);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        Spinner spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectzone);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        Spinner spinner3=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectcode);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution at

[CountryStateCitySpinner](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/tree/master/app/src/main/java/spinner/list/activities)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create three snippers in xml file and you can feed data like below

```
    List<String> areas = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> schools = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://ww");

            try {

                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    areas.add(jsonobject.optString("converternumber"));
                    schools.add(jsonobject.optString("zonenumber"));
                    classes.add(jsonobject.optString("codeid"));
                }
  .......................
  //finally u need to set those three lists to three snippers

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, area);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spin‌​ner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, school);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spin‌​ner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);


    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner3); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, class);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spin‌​ner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It is not showing any error but i cannot get the values to dropdown? any suggestions?? @Lucefer

Comment: @Arvind can u log the values and make sure your json file contains value related to that area, school and classes

Comment: Here is my Json file structure
{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":"1a","codeid":"test111"},{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":"1a","codeid":"test112"}.........

Comment: @Arvind i updated my answer related to that. now try it

Comment: @Arvind what is the name of this object array. It should be replace here jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation") instead of "worldpopulation" this

Comment: Hello again @Lucefer, it is still the same, cannot populate, do you know how to give the values to textview and then relate it to the dropdown?

Comment: @Arvind you json file should like below 
myObj = { "worldpopulation":[  {"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":"1a","codeid":"test111"},{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":"1a","codeid":"test112"}]
}

Comment: the name of the Object array is "server_response"

Comment: my json file again sorry:
{"server_response":[{"converternumber":"0","zonenumber":"","codeid":""},{"converternumber":"1","zonenumber":"23","codeid":"rg"}

Comment: @Arvind i updated code again now try it. make sure jsonobject  is there correctly by logging it